# Fetch error: cannot load resource unless page is refreshed - React

Tags: reactjs, fetch, use-effect

I created a fetch call:

```
    fetch(testURL)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify("test data", data));
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log(Error);
      });
```

In the console there's an error that the resource cannot be accessed
But when I refresh I'm able to see the url.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the fetch call in a function like this:

```
  const fetchTest = () => {
    fetch(testURL)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify("test data", data));
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log(Error);
      });
  };
```

and then call the function in a useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTest();
  }, []);
```

This will make sure the resource is loaded without the need to refresh first.